# MySQL query optimization JOIN

Tags: mysql, optimization

I need your help to optimize those mysql query, both are in my slow query logs.

```
SELECT a.nom, c.id_apps, c.id_commentaire, c.id_utilisateur,
       c.note_commentaire, u.nom_utilisateur
  FROM comments AS c
  LEFT JOIN apps AS a ON c.id_apps = a.id_apps
  LEFT JOIN users AS u ON c.id_utilisateur = u.id_utilisateur
 ORDER BY c.date_commentaire DESC LIMIT 5;
```

There is a MySQL INDEX on c.id_apps, a.id_apps, c.id_utilisateur,  u.id_utilisateur and c.date_commentaire.

EXPLAIN result:

```
id | select_type | table |  type  | possible_keys | key              | key_len | ref              | rows | Extra
1  | SIMPLE      |   c   |  index | NULL          | date_commentaire | 8       | NULL             | 119  |
1  | SIMPLE      |   a   | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY          | 3       | c.id_apps        | 1    |
1  | SIMPLE      |   u   | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY          | 3       | c.id_utilisateur | 1    |
```

---

```
SELECT a.id_apps, a.id_itunes, a.nom, a.prix, a.resume, c.nom_fr_cat, e.nom_edit
  FROM apps AS a
  LEFT JOIN cat AS c ON a.categorie = c.id_cat
  LEFT JOIN edit AS e ON a.editeur = e.id_edit
 ORDER BY a.id_apps DESC LIMIT 20;
```

EXPLAIN result:

```
id | select_type | table |  type  | possible_keys |   key   | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra
1  | SIMPLE      |   a   |  index | NULL          | PRIMARY |    3    | NULL        | 5336 |  
1  | SIMPLE      |   c   | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY |    1    | a.categorie |  1   |  
1  | SIMPLE      |   e   | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY |    3    | a.editeur   |  1   |
```

There is a MySQL INDEX on a.categorie, c.id_cat, a.editeur, e.id_edit and a.id_apps

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the query plan? Use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: Pierre, don't try to syntax-highlight by hand. Just format it as code (indent four spaces) and format it nicely. I've done it for you in this instance.

Comment: How large are the respective data sets? I notice there are no `WHERE` clauses; do you really want all comments and apps returned? Are the `LIMIT` clauses part of the design, or did you add them while testing?

Comment: Thanks guys & sorry Marcelo it's my first time on Stackoverflow

The first query with EXPLAIN:

id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra

1 SIMPLE c index NULL date_commentaire 8 NULL 119
1 SIMPLE a eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 3 c.id_apps 1
1 SIMPLE u eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 3 c.id_utilisateur 1

And the second

id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra

1 SIMPLE a index NULL PRIMARY 3 NULL 5336
1 SIMPLE c eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 1 a.categorie 1
1 SIMPLE e eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 3 a.editeur 1

There is no WHERE clause but it's normal and the a LIMIT

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys & sorry Marcelo it's my first time on Stackoverflow

The first query with EXPLAIN:

id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra

1   SIMPLE  c   index   NULL    date_commentaire    8   NULL    119
1   SIMPLE  a   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     3   c.id_apps   1
1   SIMPLE  u   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     3   c.id_utilisateur    1

And the second

id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra

1   SIMPLE  a   index   NULL    PRIMARY     3   NULL    5336
1   SIMPLE  c   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     1   a.categorie     1
1   SIMPLE  e   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     3   a.editeur   1

Comment: Looks like you have a little more to learn. SO is a Q&A site, rather than a forum. Content posted as answers should answer the question. The info you posted should go in the question. Read the FAQs (follow the link at the top of the page). For more information on formatting, click the orange question mark in the post editor toolbar.